# MYSQL extra row with repeating number

Tags: php, mysql, calculated-columns

Its quite simple but I can't get it working,

I have a table named as 'TABLE1' with many rows each with unique COLUMN1

```
COLUMN1
  1
  2
  3
  4
  5
```

I select rows from it based on other criteria

What I want the output is an extra column with the number '1' and '2' repeating

So the output should be something like

```
COLUMN1   ID
  1       1
  2       2
  4       1
  8       2
 11       1
```

and so on..

Would that be possible ?

Thanks.

Comment: What is preventing you from doing this in PHP?

Comment: How are 1 and 2 being determined?

Comment: I have a very long javascript check and a php block with each row. All the output is in one column. I want to split that in two columns, so what I thought, if I can add 1 or 2, I can make a check in PHP to echo a td or a tr. I can add row_number and then divide by 2 in php and echo based on that, but I think doing it in MYSQL would be simpler.

Comment: @JA 1 and 2 is just sequencial.. first row of the output , put 1.. second row of the output , put 2, third row of the output, put 1.. and so on..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's possible.

One way is to use a MySQL user-defined variable, and conditionally toggle the value between 1 and 2.

For example:

```
SELECT t.column1
     , IF(@i=1,@i:=2,@i:=1) AS id
  FROM mytable t
 CROSS JOIN (SELECT @i:=0) i
 ORDER BY t.column1
```

Comment: It's important to note that the MySQL Reference Manual cautions that this behavior we observe of user-defined variables within a statement is *not* guaranteed. (It works in MySQL 5.1 and 5.5. I haven't tested fully in 5.6; it's possible this behavior will change in a future release.)